# Get stored shared preference list and display in list view

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi I'm having issue where getting the stored value from Shared Preference and displaying it. It giving Future doesn't contain length instance error. My code below.

Save Shared Preference Value Code

```
Future<String> saveSearchQuery(String squery) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(prefs.getStringList("searchhistory") == null){
      final List<String> recentSearch = [];
      recentSearch.insert(0, squery);
      prefs.setStringList("searchhistory", recentSearch);
    }else{
      final recentSearch = prefs.getStringList("searchhistory");

      if(recentSearch.contains(squery)){
          recentSearch.forEach((e) => print(e));
      }else{
          recentSearch.insert(0, squery);
      }
      prefs.setStringList("searchhistory", recentSearch);
    }
    return prefs.commit().toString();
}
```

Get Shared Preference Value Code

```
Future<dynamic> getSearchHistory() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   List searchHistory = prefs.getStringList("searchhistory");
   return searchHistory.toList();
}
```

Please help. Thank you.